# for sentence in taggedOutput : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

A problem Happen Between sentence or Tagged corpus 
but I can not solve the code 
this is the sentence code

```
def loadUntagged(fileName):
    text = open(fileName).read()
    sentences = list(tokenize.blankline(text))
    retSentences = []
    for sentence in sentences:
        newSentence = []
        sentence =list(tokenize.whitespace(sentence))
        #print (sentence)
        for token in sentence:
            newSentence.append(token)
            retSentences.append(newSentence)

def loadCorpus(corpus):
    text = open(corpus).read()
    sentences =list(tokenize.blankline(self))
    newSentences = []
    for sentence in sentences:
        tokens =list(tokenize.whitespace(sentence))
```

this is `TaggedOutput` code:

```
untagged =pd.read_csv('test.csv','UTF-8','r')
print ('Tagging...')
taggedOutput = doTag(tagger,untagged)
tagged = pd.read_csv("Tagged_bangla_hmm.csv",'w',encoding="utf-8", header=None, delimiter = r'\s+',skip_blank_lines=False, engine='python')
for sentence in taggedOutput :
    for word, tag in  enumerate(tagged):
        tagged.to_csv( str(word)  + str(tag)  )
        print(tagged)
        print('\n\n')
        print ('Finished Tagging')
```

Comment: Could you post the full error trace?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HunTer\Desktop\new\training in NLTK.py", line 105, in <module>
    for sentence in taggedOutput :
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: And please add the code for `doTag` function

Comment: the main error in Trainer.Train_unsupervised([sent])

Comment: when i pass it then the key error happen